# How do I export text from a VBS input box to a text document?

Tags: input, vbscript, export

How do I export text from a VBS input box to a text document?

I Have an input box, I wish to export the text the user inputs into a separate text file.

Comment: When in doubt, read the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t5399c99%28v=vs.84%29.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

```
Dim objFSO 'File System Object
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim objTS 'Text Stream Object
Const ForWriting = 2
Set objTS = objFSO.OpenTextFile("c:\TextFile.txt", ForWriting, True)
objTS.Write(InputBox("Here it is"))
objTS.Close()
```